# Spring Security: does it provide an authentication provider for XML database?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

We are currently trying to integrate Spring Security into our application.

Our application used to store data in native XMLs. We are in the process of integrating with MySQL.

However, certain sites are still having lots of data in XML and we want to provide backward compatibility.

So does spring security provide authentication mechanism for XML based database just like it does for SQL and LDAP?

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: The Spring Security component tasked with loading information about the user to authenticate is `UserDetailsService`. There is no out-of-the-box implementation for `UserDetailsService` that can load user information from XML files. You should create your own implementation and let the framework use it.

Comment: @dur I am using native XMLs